# Is Azure Machine learning manageable by using programming languages not Drag & Drop?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service, azureportal

seems that working with machine learning right now is only available by using Drag & Drop interface online, but I am not sure. for professional usage, to add data model dynamically, train, evaluate and prediction, it need to be accessible by programming languages.

is it right now accessible by programming languages or I should upload, split, train, evaluate and predict my Data using Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0):

Right now within the Azure ML Studio environment you would need to use the modules to set up the end to end flow.

But you can write your own R/Python code within the notebook environment:  https://notebooks.azure.com/

Try the notebook environment to see if it suits your requirements.

Regards,
Jaya

Comment: Are you sure it's possible!?
as I know you can write your code in notebooks to manage and change some special parts of the way that ML is working, but it's not possible to create a ML Progress with notebooks completely. I need to do all these progress automatically without doing anything manually. upload Data Source (it's a CSV file right now and it's uploaded somewhere in Azure) into the ML portal and Create Multiclass and Regression Models using that data source. then I should train those models and finally I should predict new dynamic data!
I need to do all the prgoress programmatically..

Comment: You can do the process with code easily. What you've to do is add the "python/R" sript module for the workflow and write the code inside it.

Comment: For operationalizing a web service, it is easiest when done through the Azure ML Studio environment. You should try the new product Azure ML Workbench https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/quickstart-installation